# Just-audio in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, just-audio

It seems that using Flutter Web on iOS device(Safari and Chrome tried so far) with this plugin, if the audio is not ready(still buffering) if you try to play it, will block the execution. Should be handle or should be something to update in the documentation?
Same case on Flutter Web but on desktop device does not cause the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the very same issue but on flutter web.  In my case, it turned out to be a wrong path.  It worked in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.  Once I removed assets/ from the path (which was in the example I found), then it worked on all the browsers.